# Handling multiple themes in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, oop, themes, protocols

I'm trying to create an app that is able to handle multiple themes (not just light and dark modes). I'm seeing a suggested solution online that recommends using a theme protocol to map a schema for each theme, which then allows a ThemeManager class to switch the current theme.

```
protocol ThemeProtocol {
    var basicButtonStyle: ButtonStyle { get }
    // There will be many button styles here.
}

struct Theme1Light: ThemeProtocol {
    var basicButtonStyle: ButtonStyle { ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: .red, titleColor: .white) }
}

struct Theme1Dark: ThemeProtocol {
    var basicButtonStyle: ButtonStyle { ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: .blue, titleColor: .white) }
}

class ThemeManager {
    
    static var currentTheme: ThemeProtocol = Theme1Light()
    
    static func setTheme(theme: ThemeProtocol){
        self.currentTheme = theme
    }
    
}
```

My problem is, I'd like for my button subclass to hold a reference to the button theme that is able to automatically switch when the theme manager changes the current theme (triggered by light/dark mode being toggled). By assigning the button style to a variable, I can only capture the value at assignment which means nothing changes when the trait collection changes. It only reassigns the same values to bg colour and title colour.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    
    var style: ButtonStyle? {
        didSet {
            self.applyStyle()
        }
    }
    
    func applyStyle(){
        backgroundColor = style!.backgroundColor
        setTitleColor(style!.titleColor, for: .normal)
    }
    
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        // some logic to work out if dark / light mode change - imagine we go from light to dark here.
        ThemeManager.setTheme(theme: Theme1Dark())
        applyStyle()
    }
    
}
```

I'd love to find a way to set the button theme once and let any instances of the custom button class handle switching between light and dark themes.

```
let button: MyButton = {
    let button = MyButton()
    button.style = ThemeManager.currentTheme.basicButtonStyle
    return button
}()
```

Can anyone think of a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Would [this](https://infinum.com/blog/implementing-dynamic-color-themes-in-your-ios-app/) work for you? It's quite a different approach from what you are doing here, using `appearance()` instead of manually setting the colors for each button.

Comment: I looked into this but struggled to find a way to have it manage multiple different button themes.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific? Do you mean you find it hard to create differently-styled of buttons in the same theme? How about making different `UIButton` subclasses for each button style?

Comment: Yes @Sweeper that's right... I imagine more than just one style within each theme. The two solutions I already thought about are either subclassing each style as you mention (So MyButtonBasic, MyButtonSecondary etc), or having the parent class (view controller for example) re-assign the style object when the trait collection changes. I guess I was just curious if there are other solutions available that follow my desired instantiation flow from above.